# How to deal with the dimension of time (historic) in Cassandra while optimising for speed?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

We are dealing with a situation where we store items with an X amount of properties (it is a SaaS solution and every instance has a different amount of properties). What we are struggling with is the dimension of time.

What would be the best way to store the data if we want to be able to:

1. Quickly get individual items.
2. Get the value of a property with a certain timestamp (ie, historic info).

*Note: we do not want to search for property values, we want speed :-) We will have many items with many properties, with many timestamps that we should be able to fetch as fast as possible.*

Example use case of the SaaS solution: We have a ship with 10.000 sensors, they collect temperature every minute. This means that we have 10.000 "items" with "temperature" as one of the properties. They will be updated every minute and we want to store the history.

**Option 1. Store all in maps (Id = Primary Key)**

```
------------------------------------------------
Id | Name | Props
------------------------------------------------
1  | Foo  | map<timestamp, map<name, text>>
------------------------------------------------
2  | Bar  | map<timestamp, map<name, text>>
------------------------------------------------
```

In the map we will have something like:

```
{
    "1518023285": {
        "propName": "Prop A",
        "propValue": "Value A"
    },
    "1518011111": {
        "propName": "Prop A",
        "propValue": "Value B"
    },
    "1518011111": {
        "propName": "Prop B",
        "propValue": "Value C"
    }
}
```

`Prop A` and `Prop B` are created at the same time, `Prop A` got updated.

We will collect the complete item and use our application to find the right value at the right time.

**Option 2. Store time in maps and props as rows (Id = Primary Key)**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Id | Name | Prop_A               | Prop_B
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  | Foo  | map<timestamp, text> | map<timestamp, text>
-----------------------------------------------------------
2  | Bar  | map<timestamp, text> | map<timestamp, text>
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

In the column `Prop_A` we will have something like:

```
{
    "1518023285": "Value B",
    "1518011111": "Value A"
}
```

Meaning that `Prop_A` got created with `Value A` and updated later with `Value B`.

We will collect the complete item and use our application to find the right value at the right time.

**Option 3. Properties in a map and time in a row (Id = Primary Key, ItemId has index, Time has index)**

```
-------------------------------------------------
Id | ItemId | Name | Time       | Props
-------------------------------------------------
1  | 1      | Foo  | 1518011111 | map<name, text>
-------------------------------------------------
2  | 2      | Bar  | 1518011111 | map<name, text>
-------------------------------------------------
3  | 2      | Bar  | 1518023285 | map<name, text>
-------------------------------------------------
```

A map will look like:

```
{
    "Prop A": "Value A",
    "Prop B": "Value B"
}
```

We will collect *all* rows of items and find the right time in our application

**Option 4. Properties and time in a row (Id = Primary Key, ItemId has index, Time has index)**

```
----------------------------------------------------
Id | ItemId | Name | Time       | Prop_A   | Prop_B
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 1      | Foo  | 1518011111 | Value A  | Value B
----------------------------------------------------
2  | 2      | Bar  | 1518011111 | Value A  | Value B
----------------------------------------------------
3  | 2      | Bar  | 1518023285 | Value A  | Value C
----------------------------------------------------
```

Row 3 got updated.

We create 2 CQL queries, one to find the latest version and seconly to collect the props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for option 3, but with a similar change to what Chris is proposing:

```
((id, item_id), time, name, map)
```

If the maps don't change in each timestamp (meaning they are read-only for that timestamp), I don't see a downside with taking advantage of the collection. It will also save you some disk space having all the properties in one map, instead of having them in separate columns.

Comment: Thanks, Pedro, would it not be a problem that the map can grow into the millions?

Comment: @BobvanLuijt As long as you don't go above the recommended partition size (100 MB), I don't see a problem (sorry for the super delayed response :)). Check this: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations

Answer (score 2):

CQL collections are (with some exceptions) completely deserialized into memory, this could be really bad long term. Especially from a perf perspective its less than ideal, they are for convenience with smaller maps, not performance.

I would actually recommend something like Option 4, like: `((id, item_id), name, time, prop)` where prop can just be "A" or "B" and a value field for its value. if "prop" is really limited to just A-C or something, can switch time and prop so you can query for timelines of each property and just make a few queries merged together. Be sure to change ordering of time so that the recent data is at beginning of partition for more efficient reads on getting latest value. If theres a ton of inserts you will want too break up the partitions more, maybe including a "year-month" to your partition key.